# Pandas reorder data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

This is probably an easy one using pivot, but since I am not adding the numbers (every row is unique) how should I go about doing this?

Input:

```
      Col1   Col2 Col3
0    123.0   33.0  ABC
1    345.0   39.0  ABC
2    567.0  100.0  ABC
3    123.0   82.0  PQR
4    345.0   10.0  PQR
5    789.0   38.0  PQR
6    890.0   97.0  XYZ
7    345.0   96.0  XYZ
```

Output:

```
      Col1    ABC   PQR   XYZ
0    123.0   33.0  82.0   NaN
1    345.0   39.0  10.0  96.0
2    567.0  100.0   NaN   NaN
3    789.0    NaN  38.0   NaN
4    890.0    NaN   NaN  97.0
```

And could I get this output in dataframe format then pls? Thanks so much for taking a look!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html):

```
print (df.pivot(index='Col1', columns='Col3', values='Col2'))
Col3     ABC   PQR   XYZ
Col1                    
123.0   33.0  82.0   NaN
345.0   39.0  10.0  96.0
567.0  100.0   NaN   NaN
789.0    NaN  38.0   NaN
890.0    NaN   NaN  97.0
```

Another solution with [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) and [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html):

```
print (df.set_index(['Col1','Col3'])['Col2'].unstack())
Col3     ABC   PQR   XYZ
Col1                    
123.0   33.0  82.0   NaN
345.0   39.0  10.0  96.0
567.0  100.0   NaN   NaN
789.0    NaN  38.0   NaN
890.0    NaN   NaN  97.0
```

---

EDIT by comment:

Need [`pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html):

```
print (df.pivot_table(index='Col1', columns='Col3', values='Col2'))
Col3     ABC   PQR   XYZ
Col1                    
123.0   33.0  82.0   NaN
345.0   39.0  10.0  96.0
567.0  100.0   NaN   NaN
789.0    NaN  38.0   NaN
890.0    NaN   NaN  97.0
```

Another faster solution with [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html), aggregating `mean` (by default `pivot_table` aggreagate `mean` also), convert to `Series` by [`DataFrame.squeeze`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.squeeze.html) and last [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html):

```
print (df.groupby(['Col1','Col3']).mean().squeeze().unstack())
Col3     ABC   PQR   XYZ
Col1                    
123.0   33.0  82.0   NaN
345.0   39.0  10.0  96.0
567.0  100.0   NaN   NaN
789.0    NaN  38.0   NaN
890.0    NaN   NaN  97.0
```

Comment: Thanks so much.. let me check the 2nd one.. the 1st one is what I tried and gave me this error : 'ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape'

Comment: input_.set_index(['Col1','Col3'])['Col2'].unstack()
also gives
ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape

Comment: Yes, so I add another solution with link for better explanation.